# Failed to set Database.DefaultConnectionFactory to an instance of the 'MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity'

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, nuget

I followed http://dleusden.blogspot.in/2013/09/mysql-55-and-ef-5-code-first.html to create my first application in MySQL + Entity framework but it results in following error.`

```
    System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Failed to set Database.DefaultConnectionFactory to an instance of the 'MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity' type as specified in the application configuration. See inner exception for details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.<.ctor>b__3()
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.TryGetDefaultConnectionFactory()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetServiceFactory(Type type, String name)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 t)
       at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[T](IDbDependencyResolver resolver)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
       at MyFirstEF.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Sandbox\MyFirstEF\MyFirstEF\Program.cs:line 23
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
       HResult=-2147024894
       Message=Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data.Entity' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
       Source=mscorlib
       FileName=MySql.Data.Entity
       FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = MySql.Data.Entity
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: MySql.Data.Entity | Domain ID: 1
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/Sandbox/MyFirstEF/MyFirstEF/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\Sandbox\MyFirstEF\MyFirstEF\bin\Debug\MyFirstEF.vshost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Sandbox/MyFirstEF/MyFirstEF/bin/Debug/MySql.Data.Entity.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Sandbox/MyFirstEF/MyFirstEF/bin/Debug/MySql.Data.Entity/MySql.Data.Entity.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Sandbox/MyFirstEF/MyFirstEF/bin/Debug/MySql.Data.Entity.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Sandbox/MyFirstEF/MyFirstEF/bin/Debug/MySql.Data.Entity/MySql.Data.Entity.EXE.

       StackTrace:
            at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
            at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
            at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
            at System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.DefaultConnectionFactoryElement.GetFactoryType()
            at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.<.ctor>b__3()
       InnerException:
```

**My Main method**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MySqlContext>());

        var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ToString();



        using (var db = new MySqlContext(connString))
        {
            var customer = new Customer { LastName = "van Leusden", FirstName = "Dimitris" };
            db.Customers.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("All ok!");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

**My App Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>

<!--<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>-->

<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity" />
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory,MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="server=localhost;Database=testef;uid=root;pwd=administrator;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**My MySQlContext.cs**

```
class MySqlContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public MySqlContext(string connString)
        : base(connString)
    { }
}
```

**My Customer.cs**

```
class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

**MyFirstEF Project file**

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
<ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
<SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
<ProjectGuid>{3C057471-6629-4C18-A7BC-A132339FA444}</ProjectGuid>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
<RootNamespace>MyFirstEF</RootNamespace>
<AssemblyName>MyFirstEF</AssemblyName>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<TargetFrameworkProfile>
</TargetFrameworkProfile>
<FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<Optimize>false</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
<Optimize>true</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="EntityFramework">
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.2\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer">

<HintPath>..\packages\
 EntityFramework.6.0.2\lib\net40\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 6.8.3\Assemblies\v4.0\MySql.Data.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="MySql.Data.Entity, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 6.8.3\Assemblies\v4.0\MySql.Data.Entity.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 6.8.3\Assemblies\v4.0\MySql.Web.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
<Reference Include="System.configuration" />
<Reference Include="System.Core" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
<Reference Include="System.Data" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Include="Customer.cs" />
<Compile Include="MySqlContext.cs" />
<Compile Include="Program.cs" />
<Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<None Include="App.config">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</None>
<None Include="packages.config" />
</ItemGroup>
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
 <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
   Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
</Target>
-->
</Project>
```

Comment: Did you install everything with `NuGet`? Can you take a look in the `Bin\Debug` directory and check that the expected library DLLs are all being copied into it?

Comment: @ChrisBallard I installed  the EF through NuGet and Mysql products using mysql-installer-web-community-5.6.16.0 . I do not find any Mysql related dll under Bin/Debug folder. But there are dlls related to EF.

Comment: That will be your problem then. Can you open the `.csproj` file in a text editor and past this at the bottom of your question. We should be able to sort the issue then!

Comment: @ChrisBallard I updated my project file. But I am not sure why mysql dlls are missing!?

Comment: Its possible this is a red herring, and these are all coming from the GAC - but to be certain, can you try manually copying those 3 DLLs from their current location to your `bin\Debug` directory, and see if that cures the problem?

Comment: @ChrisBallard sorry it did not solve also I added MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll too but same error